# Zip file failed to unzip using Python but extracted sucessfully on the Windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, unzip

I am trying to unzip a .zip file using Python zipfile but got an error message below:

> zipfile.BadZipFile: Corrupt extra field 7953 (size=29811)

So I tried it on the Windows (win11), it can be extracted without any problem.
Then I zipped it again using the Windows app and this time this re-zipped file works fine by my python program.

just using a sample code:

```
with ZipFile(file_path, "r") as zip:
     zip.extractall()
```

Is there any way to get rid of that extra field problem?
Thanks.

Comment: You just said how to get rid of the problem. Unzip and rezip. The Python thing looks like a bug, since if an extra field cannot be interpreted, then the unzipper should simply ignore it and move on. Can you provide a link to this zip file?